# Wrap a given input string in double quotes if not already wrapped

Tags: javascript, regex, string

**Background**

I need to wrap a JavaScript string in double quotes BUT only if the input string is not already wrapped in double quotes. For this question's purposes "wrapped" is considered as beginning and ending in a double quote regardless of grammar rules.

**The Question**

What's the best way (regex?) to wrap any input string (empty string included) in double quotes while avoiding duplicate wrapping? Solution should handle internal quotes assuming they are already escaped.

Example inputs/results:

Input:

```
Hello world
```

Result:

```
"Hello world"
```

Input:

```
"Hello world"
```

Result:

```
"Hello world"
```

Input:

```
A quick example says \"hello world\"
```

Result:

```
"A quick example says \"hello world\""
```

Input:

```
*empty string*
```

Result:

```
""
```

Input:

```
"Hi," he said, "How are you?"
```

Result: (considered "wrapped"):

```
"Hi," he said, "How are you?"
```

Comment: Can the string have internal double quotes? If so, would they need to be escaped if the string wasn't already wrapped in double quotes? What if they were already escaped? How would you want to handle something like `"Hi," he said, "How are you?"`. Is that "wrapped in double quotes"? Or should the result be `""Hi," he said, "How are you?""`?

Comment: Question revised. Internal quotes can be assumed as already escaped

Comment: Your revision doesn't address every case. For instsance, how would you distinguish that  last from `"He said "hi" to me"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "already escaped"? What if the string contains double-quotes that are *not* preceded by backslashes, like you had in your question before you edited it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short and simple way is just to test the first and last characters:

```
var input = // whatever
var wrapped = input;
if ('"' === wrapped || !('"' === wrapped[0] && '"' === wrapped.slice(-1)))
  wrapped = '"' + wrapped + '"';
```

(This works even on empty strings, because `''[0]` is `undefined` and `''.slice(-1)` is `''`, neither of which cause a problem in the `if` condition.)

You don't say what to do if the input is just a single double-quote character, but I've assumed for the input `'"'` the output will be `'"""'`. If that's not what you want obviously you can modify the code above.

Comment: This appears to cover all of the cases. Regarding the input string as a single double quote, your solution result suffices

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using a regex. I'll assume from your examples and comments that the following preconditions hold:

- internal quotes, if present, are already escaped
- the string is either properly wrapped in (unescaped) double quotes or there are no unescaped double quotes (that is, there is never an unescaped double quote at one end and not the other)

If those assumptions are valid, the problem is much simpler. Just test whether the string starts with a double quote (which perforce wouldn't be escaped, since it's the first character) and whether it ends with an unescaped double quote. If only one is missing, you have a string that doesn't conform to the input assumptions. If both are missing, wrap the string; if neither is missing, the string is already wrapped.

Besides checking for an empty string, you also have to check for a string that consists entirely of one double quote.

Comment: @nnnnnn 's answer was selected because it avoids regex like you mentioned but actually contained a js snippet. Up vote for explanation

Comment: @CalebAdams - Entirely appropriate. He has a nice solution and good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You guessed it right. The best bay would be to use regex to wrap your string around quotes. Something like below:-

```js
function quoteMe() {
  var inpStr = document.getElementById("input");
  inpStr.value = '"' + inpStr.value.replace(/"/g, '') + '"'
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inpStr.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" id="input" />
<input type="button" value="Quote Me!" onclick="javascript:quoteMe();">
<div id="result">

</div>
```

;

Comment: But...the question says that quotes already within the string should be retained.

Comment: Yes. the code would effectively trim the quotes and add again. So effectively they would be retained

Comment: I don't see how they would be retained

Comment: On running the snippet above, when you give input as test, it returns "test". When you give input as "test" it returns "test" (quotes are retained)

Comment: Your code removes *all* quotes. Look at the examples in the question that have quotes in the middle of the input string.

Answer (score -1):

I would first take the string and replace double quotes then just add.

```
var res = str.replace('"', '');
res = '"' + res + '"'
```

Comment: That wouldn't be very kind to the string `"She said \"Hello\""` (if such strings are allowed in OP's application).

Comment: Yes, Ted is right. It should be able to handle quotes within the string itself.